# Templates not changing when template binding changes

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a page where I want to change which template is used to display a list of items (for example a simple vs an advanced view). Sample code:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="template1">
    Template 1
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="template2">
    Template 2
</script>

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: viewSelect"/>
<button data-bind="click: newArray">Refresh Array</button>
<ul data-bind="template:{name: templateBinding, foreach: items}">
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.viewSelect = ko.observable();

    this.newArray = function(){
        console.log("newArray");
        self.items([{text:"Item1"},{text:"Item2"},{text:"Item3"}]);
    };

    this.templateBinding = ko.computed(function(){
        console.log("templateBinding");
        if(self.viewSelect()){
            return "template1";
        } else{
            return "template2";
        }
    });

    this.items = ko.observableArray([{text:"Item1"},{text:"Item2"},{text:"Item3"}]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JgLE/) with this code.

Here's what's happening: I'm expecting Knockout to re-create the displayed list when the template changes. The `computed` hooked to `templateBinding` is called (this can be confirmed from the console), but the template does not change, toggling the checkbox does not change the display. However, changes to the contents of the array does refresh the list, with the new template.

Is there an elegant way of doing this, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a dynamic template name for items in a foreach, you will need to specify a function to execute. This will be called for each item (and will pass the item as the first arg).

So, you could change your current code to:

```
this.getTemplate = function(){
    if(self.viewSelect()){
        return "template1";
    } else{
        return "template2";
    }
};
```

and bind like:

```
<ul data-bind="template:{name: getTemplate, foreach: items}">
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qAEXh/

Comment: Works a treat. Though I wonder why this works, but binding to an observable doesn't.

Comment: just the way that the template binding works with `foreach` currently. when calling a function on each, it ensures that each has its own dependency.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better that it used the same observable pattern like the rest of KO? :D

Comment: In a `foreach` it specifically allows you to choose a different template per item by calling the function and passing the item as the first arg.